# Finding Out if a Value in a Generated Array Exists Without Getting a Notice

Tags: php

I have an array, `$beerArray`, that is obtained from parsing data from a JSON API and putting it into a PHP array. There are certain values, like $beer_name, that I expect to be in the JSON data but aren't always there, causing that value to not exist in the array. I've set up some if... else statements to adjust for these cases:

```
if (!($beerArray->response->beer->beer_name)) {
    do something
    }   

else {
    do something else
    }   
}
```

This prevents errors like trying to assign a variable to an array value that doesn't exist, but I still get this pesky Notice:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$beer_name in /Users/x_/Documents/html/php/populatebeer.php on line 66
```

Is there a better way to structure my logic to avoid these notices? It fills the log with false positives which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Use the isset() function. Simply pass the variable you wish to see is set or not and this function will return true if the variable exists or false if it does not.

For example change your if statement to:

```
if (!isset($beerArray->response->beer->beer_name)) {
```

The first block executes if there is no beer_name set. The 2nd block executes if it has a name

Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php